# Jenkins Pipeline returns wrong workspace path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline with a pipeline script stored in a repository. This pipeline is working well with Jenkins **2.114**. After installing a new Jenkins **2.187** on a new machine with all corresponding plugins, I am facing a problem of wrong current directory path returned from `pwd()` function on this new installation.

Within the pipeline script I am calling pwd() in order to get the current work-space path (the current OS working directory). The returned path is wrong, it even does not exist. `env.WORKSPACE` returns exactly the same wrong path.

The pipeline creates two folders in the work-space:

`{Jenkins_Workspace}/{item_full_name}@script` and  `{Jenkins_Workspace}/{item_full_name}@3`.

The returned value from pwd() is `{Jenkins_Workspace}/{item_full_name}@2` . env.WORKSPCE gives the same path `{Jenkins_Workspace}/{item_full_name}@2`. 
`{Jenkins_Workspace}/{item_full_name}@2` does not exist.

It is strange that Jenkins appends @{number} to the workspace.  It is a very simple pipeline, which does not execute other projects. It is just one job being executed, i.e. no concurrency.

**My configuration:**

- Jenkins: 2.187
- Pipeline: 2.6
- OS: Windows Server 2016
- Jre: 1.8.0_144-b01
- Jenkins home: C:/Jenkins
- Jenkins workspace: modified in config.xml to <workspace>D:/Workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspace>

Any ideas what can be reason for this problem are highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to open an issue on issues.jenkins-ci.org?

Comment: I've created a Jenkins issue JENKINS-58802

Comment: did you get any solution? I don't see much update on the [JENKINS-58802](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58802) ticket.